# Proving a formula about binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

I found the following formula in a book without any proof:

$$\sum_{j=k}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor}{\binom{n}{2j}}{\binom{j}{k}}=\frac{n}{n-k}\cdot2^{n-2k-1}{\binom{n-k}{k}}$$
where $n$ is a natural number and $k$ is an integer which satisfies $0\le k \le\frac n2$.

I've tried to prove this, but I'm facing difficulty. Could you show me how to prove this?

Comment: Have you tried Gosper's algorithm?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Sorry, but I don't know it.

Comment: I am facing a very similar problem!, see [this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380345/connection-between-hermite-legendre-polynomials/499877#499877) to a certain question relating Hermite and Legendre polynomials. At the end I struggled (without success so far) with a sum of the same kind as the one above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just been able to prove this relational expression.

I'm going to use the followings :

$$\cos{n\theta}=n\sum_{l=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\{(-1)^l\cdot2^{n-2l-1}\cdot\frac{\binom{n-l}{l}}{n-l}\cos^{n-2l}{\theta}\}\ \ \ \cdots(\star),$$
$$\sin{n\theta}=\sum_{l=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\{(-1)^l\cdot2^{n-2l-1}\cdot\binom{n-l-1}{l}\cos^{n-2l-1}{\theta}\sin\theta\}\ \ \ \cdots(\star\star).$$

(We can get $(\star)$ by induction about $n$. Also, we can get $(\star\star)$ by differentiating $(\star)$.)

**Proof** : Comparing the both sides of 
$$\cos{n\theta}+i\sin{n\theta}=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\cos^{n-k}\theta(i\sin)^k,$$
we get
$$\cos{n\theta}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\cos^{n-2k}{\theta}(\cos^2\theta-1)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\cos^{n-2k}{\theta}\cdot\sum_{l=0}^{k}\{\binom{k}{l}\cos^{2(k-l)}{\theta}\cdot(-1)^l\}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\sum_{l=0}^{k}\{(-1)^l\cdot\binom{n}{2k}\cdot\binom{k}{l}\cdot\cos^{n-2l}{\theta}\}.$$
Hence, we know that the coefficient of $\cos^{n-2l}\theta$ is
$$\sum_{k=l}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^l\cdot\binom{n}{2k}\cdot\binom{k}{l}.$$

On the other hand, $(\star)$ tells us that the coefficient of $\cos^{n-2l}\theta$ is
$$n\cdot(-1)^l\cdot2^{n-2l-1}\cdot\frac{\binom{n-l}{l}}{n-l}.$$

Hence, we get 
$$\sum_{k=l}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\cdot\binom{k}{l}=n\cdot2^{n-2l-1}\cdot\frac{\binom{n-l}{l}}{n-l}$$
as desired. Now the proof is completed.

**P.S.** By the same argument about $\sin{n\theta}$, we can get
$$\sum_{j=k}^{\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}\binom{n}{2j+1}\cdot\binom{j}{k}=2^{n-2k-1}\binom{n-k-1}{k}$$
for $n\ge 2k+1$.

Answer (score 2):

We will use induction to prove the identity (equivalent to the one given) that

1) $\displaystyle\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n}{2j}\binom{j}{k}=2^{n-2k-1}\bigg[\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}\bigg]$ $\;\;$for $0\le k\le\frac{n}{2}$ and the identity

2) $\displaystyle\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n}{2j+1}\binom{j}{k}=2^{n-2k-1}\binom{n-k-1}{k}$ $\;\;$for $0\le k\le\frac{n-1}{2}$.

If $n=1$, $k=0$ and both sides of both identities are 1;

so assume that both identities are valid for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

1) $\displaystyle\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n+1}{2j}\binom{j}{k}=\sum_{j\ge0}\bigg[\binom{n}{2j}+\binom{n}{2j-1}\bigg]\binom{j}{k}=\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n}{2j}\binom{j}{k}+\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n}{2j-1}\binom{j}{k}$
$\;\;\;\displaystyle=\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n}{2j}\binom{j}{k}+\sum_{l\ge0}\binom{n}{2l+1}\binom{l+1}{k}$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n}{2j}\binom{j}{k}+\sum_{l\ge0}\binom{n}{2l+1}\bigg[\binom{l}{k}+\binom{l}{k-1}\bigg]$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n}{2j}\binom{j}{k}+\sum_{l\ge0}\binom{n}{2l+1}\binom{l}{k}+\sum_{l\ge0}\binom{n}{2l+1}\binom{l}{k-1}$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=2^{n-2k-1}\bigg[\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}\bigg]+2^{n-2k-1}\binom{n-k-1}{k}+2^{n-2k+1}\binom{n-k}{k-1}$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=2^{n-2k-1}\bigg[\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-k-1}{k}+4\binom{n-k}{k-1}\bigg]$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=2^{n-2k-1}\bigg[\binom{n-k+1}{k}+\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k}{k-1}+2\binom{n-k}{k-1}\bigg]$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=2^{n-2k-1}\bigg[2\binom{n-k+1}{k}+2\binom{n-k}{k-1}\bigg]=2^{n-2k}\bigg[\binom{n-k+1}{k}+\binom{n-k}{k-1}\bigg]$,

$\;\;\;\;$ so identity 1) holds for $n+1$.

2) $\displaystyle\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n+1}{2j+1}\binom{j}{k}=\sum_{j\ge0}\bigg[\binom{n}{2j+1}+\binom{n}{2j}\bigg]\binom{j}{k}=\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n}{2j+1}\binom{j}{k}+\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{n}{2j}\binom{j}{k}$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=2^{n-2k-1}\binom{n-k-1}{k}+2^{n-2k-1}\bigg[\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}\bigg]$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=2^{n-2k-1}\bigg[\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k}+\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}\bigg]=2^{n-2k-1}\bigg[\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{n-k}{k}\bigg]$

$\;\;\;\displaystyle=2^{n-2k}\binom{n-k}{k}$,

$\;\;\;$so identity 2) holds for $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

We seek to prove that

$$\sum_{j=k}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
{n\choose 2j} {j\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{n}{n-k} 2^{n-2k} {n-k\choose k}$$

where $0\le k\le n/2.$ We have for the LHS

$$[z^n] (1+z)^n \sum_{j\ge k} z^{2j} {j\choose k}.$$

Here we have extended to infinity due to the coefficient extractor.
Continuing,

$$[z^n] z^{2k} (1+z)^n \sum_{j\ge 0} z^{2j} {j+k\choose k}
= [z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^n \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{k+1}}
\\ = [z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^{n-k-1} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+1}}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-2k} {n-k-1\choose q} {n-k-q\choose k}
\\ = \frac{1}{n-k}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2k} (n-k-q) {n-k\choose q} {n-k-q\choose k}.$$

Now observe that

$${n-k\choose q} {n-k-q\choose k}
= \frac{(n-k)!}{q!\times k!\times (n-2k-q)!}
= {n-k\choose k} {n-2k\choose q}.$$

This yields

$$\frac{1}{n-k} {n-k\choose k}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2k} (n-k-q) {n-2k\choose q}.$$

The sum produces two pieces, the first is

$$(n-k) 2^{n-2k}$$

by inspection. The second is

$$- \sum_{q=0}^{n-2k} q {n-2k\choose q}
= - (n-2k) \sum_{q=1}^{n-2k} {n-2k-1\choose q-1}
\\ = - (n-2k) 2^{n-2k-1}.$$

Collecting everything we have

$$\frac{1}{n-k} {n-k\choose k} 
2^{n-2k} (n-k - \frac{1}{2} (n-2k))
= \frac{1}{n-k} {n-k\choose k}
2^{n-2k} \frac{1}{2} n.$$

This is the claim.